# Is `y = x = x + 1;` undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Is this code:

```
y = x = x + 1;
```

undefined behavior in C?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Answer to your question**
No.

**What will happen**
This will happen:

```
int x = 1; /* ASSUME THIS IS SO */
y = x = x + 1;

/* Results: */
y == 2;
x == 2;
```

**How it compiles**
The same as:

```
x += 1;
y = x;
```

**Why this is not undefined**
Because you are not writing `x` in the same expression you read it. You just set it to itself `+ 1`, then assign `y` to the value of `x`.

**Your future**
If you find the code confusing you can use parentheses for readability:

```
y = x = (x + 1);
```

Comment: Just for your info, muntoo, as the "return value" of assignment is it's own value, you can also use it for other things, like `if ( 1 == x = 1 )`, which is a pretty common bug and the reason, developers prefer to write `1 == x` instead of `x == 1` (because you can't assign x to 1).

Comment: The only developers I know who write things like `1 == x` are ones I would not work with...

Comment: @andre: No, "developers" don't prefer to write that. It's gross, unclean, and useless; just join the last decade and turn on your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 17):

No, your expression is properly defined. You probably were looking for `y = x = x++;`, which is not.

Comment: Wouldn't `y = x = x++;` be equal to `y = x = x; x += 1;`? Why wouldn't  that be properly defined?

Comment: Or would it be equivalent to `y = x = x + 1; x += 1;`, or to `y = x + 1 = x; x += 1;`?

Comment: I was asking because I wasn't sure and I wanted to know why `x + 1` was ok, but `x++` wasn't.

Comment: That example statement is supposed to change the value of `x` twice. The problem is that the C++ language does not tell in what order that would happen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Is this true for C also?

Answer (score 9):

No. You only modify `x` once, and due to the right-associativity of `=` that assignment happens before the assignment to `y`. Even if it did happen after, there's still only one modification of `x`. Your statement is as legal as `y = ++x`.