# C++ vector member initialization

Tags: c++

I am confused about the output in the following program about the `vec` in `Test`. Why it's a vector with size 100 instead of 1? I thought `std::vector<T> var{a}` is the same as `std::vector<T> var = {a}`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct Value {
   int a;
   int b;
};

class Test {
  public:
    std::vector<struct Value> vec{100};  
};

class Test2 {
  public:
    std::vector<int> vec{100};  
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    std::cout << "test size: " << test.vec.size() << std::endl;
    Test2 test2;
    std::cout << "test2 size: " << test2.vec.size();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test size: 100
test2 size: 1
```

Comment: The standards committee could have avoided this mess by choosing a different syntax for initializer lists, like <a,b,c>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::vector` has a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) with a `std::initializer_list<T>` argument. When using an initializer list like `{100}` this constructor will always take priority, if it is applicable.

For a `std::vector<int>` the initializer `{100}` is compatible with `std::initializer_list<int>` so that constructor will be used. It will create a vector containing the collection `{100}` which is a single `int` with the value `100`.

For `std::vector<Value>` the initializer `{100}` is NOT compatible with a `std::initializer_list<Value>` argument. `Value` has no converting constructor for turning an `int` to a `Value` so you cannot construct a `std::initializer_list<Value>` from `{100}`. You can verify that this conversion is not allowed with [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/WhjGbe3KP). The compiler will try to take a lower priority constructor instead, and will use the constructor which initializes 100 default constructed `Value`.

If you add a `Value::Value(int)` constructor or use `{{100}}` as the initializer for `Test2` you will find that the `std::vector<Value>` will now only contain a single element. In both cases, the initializer list is convertible to `std::initializer_list<Value>` and that constructor will now be used.

Comment: `std::initializer_list<Value>{100}` does compile though.

Comment: Ah, C++.  Always ready to bite your ankles.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That doesn't actually seem to compile when I try it : https://godbolt.org/z/f5Kos3eKj

Comment: [Clang accepts it.](https://godbolt.org/z/ejszfMhaE) :(

Comment: I've [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71070894/2752075) about it.

Answer (score 4):

As you discovered the meaning of `{100}`, changes for `T == int`.

**To answer your question briefly:**

The `100` in `vector<Value>{100}` cannot be interpreted as a `Value` and therefore the size constructor takes precedence.

If you insist, `{100}` can be interpreted as `Value`, so you may need an extra curly braces, `vector<Value>{ {100} }`.

See the illustration here: https://godbolt.org/z/xcMT1oc5z

**My advice, avoiding further discussion on legalities, is the following:**

To keep the meaning across types, initialize consistently parenthesis for size-initialization and brackets for element(s), which forces you to do this:

```
    std::vector<int> vec = std::vector<int>(100);
```

And in general:

```
    std::vector<T> vec = std::vector<T>(100);
```

In this case `100` is always the size.

Comment: Why does the meaning change between `int` and `Value`?

Comment: This is good info, but I think the question is _"Why is it a vector with size 100 instead of 1?"_

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Because for `T == int`, `{100}` can be interpreted a posteriori as a list of one element, the element being `100`.

Comment: @DrewDormann, for `T` not an integer, `{100}` can **not** be interpreted as a list of one element of type `T`, so the constructor that takes a "size" takes precedence.

Comment: @alfC But why is that not the case for `Value` as well? It is an aggregate type, you can initialize a `Value` like this `Value x{100};` and it works just fine. Edit : If you add a `Value(int)` constructor it now constructs a vector with a single instance of `Value`. So it isn't as simple as you seem to be making it out to be.

Comment: The literal `100` cannot be converted to `Value`. Perhaps `{100}` can. But in that case you would need to write `std::vector<Value>{{100}};`.

Comment: @alfC That seems to me like it is integral to answering the question and should be part of the answer.

Comment: To clarify my comment - this answer seems to be advice, and these comments seem to be the answer.

Comment: I am not trying to be a language lawyer here, since the rules are not intuitive or consistent my recommendation is to initialize from "size" always from parenthesis `(size)` and initialize from elements always with curly braces `{elements...}`.

Comment: @DrewDormann, yes, I will try to add a short paragraph so it answers the question rather.

Comment: To add insult to the damage, when declared as a local variable inside a function, `vector<int>{100}` would be resolved to "size" constructor. E.g. `int main(){ std::vector<int> vec{100}; /* vec.size() is 100*/ }`

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov Can't reproduce, prints `1` for me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you're right, I've printed `size` for the wrong var :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a totally helpful answer, but I decided to put a breakpoint in the class declaration for vector in the STD library.

### Answer

In the definition of a vector, there are 3 ways it handles the assignment.
A struct will provide a value-construction, where as an int will be assigned as a sized range construction.

It reads `std::vector<struct> vect{100};`  as building a vector of length 100, while `std::vector<int> vect{100};` is acting *similarly* `vect.insert(v.end(),100);`

This is based on the type of object passed in for .

For information's sake, the final option is taking a given value, and assigning it to a number of spots. So if you had 100, "x", it would put "x" into your vector 100 times.

### The Journey

What I learned from this is that there's a point where your vector takes a size_type input and a _Valty&& input (which I don't know what that is yet. Will be looking it up later) and provides a construction between 3 different args.

My best guess would be that your struct is filling in for 1-args path and acts as a length declaration, while int as a native type falls into the 2-args path and acts as a value assignment.

The sizeof(Value) may == 0, while the size of an int will be 1.

**Edit:** I guessed 1 and 2 (or _Count == 0, and Count == 1), however I was wrong about this. It's _Count == 0 and _Count == 2. Which was very interesting.

```cpp
    template <class... _Valty>
    _CONSTEXPR20 void _Construct_n(_CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW const size_type _Count, _Valty&&... _Val) {
        // Dispatches between the three sized constructions.
        // 1-arg -> value-construction, e.g. vector(5)
        // 2-arg -> fill, e.g. vector(5, "meow")
        // 3-arg -> sized range construction, e.g. vector{"Hello", "Fluffy", "World"}
        auto& _Al       = _Getal(); //////////////// For test1, _Count is 100, for test2, _Count is 1;
        auto&& _Alproxy = _GET_PROXY_ALLOCATOR(_Alty, _Al);
        auto& _My_data  = _Mypair._Myval2;
        _Container_proxy_ptr<_Alty> _Proxy(_Alproxy, _My_data);


        if (_Count != 0) {
            _Buy_nonzero(_Count);
            _Tidy_guard<vector> _Guard{this};

// This one happens with a struct
if constexpr (sizeof...(_Val) == 0) {
                _My_data._Mylast = _Uninitialized_value_construct_n(_My_data._Myfirst, _Count, _Al);
            } else 


if constexpr (sizeof...(_Val) == 1) {
                _STL_INTERNAL_STATIC_ASSERT(is_same_v<_Valty..., const _Ty&>);
                _My_data._Mylast = _Uninitialized_fill_n(_My_data._Myfirst, _Count, _Val..., _Al);
            } else 

// This one happens with an int
if constexpr (sizeof...(_Val) == 2) {
                _My_data._Mylast = _Uninitialized_copy(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)..., _My_data._Myfirst, _Al);
            } else {
                static_assert(_Always_false<_Ty>, "Should be unreachable");
            }
            _Guard._Target = nullptr;
        }

        _Proxy._Release();
    }
```

What's really interesting as that it appears to be happening when the Allocator reference is assigned. I'm by no means an expert in the language, but I really wanted to figure this puzzle one! Thanks for the interesting challenge!

If you've never walked through a class definition before, I would recommend trying it out.

Comment: Beware that standard library classes aren't written according to the same rules as user classes. They are written specifically targeting a specific architecture or compiler and can rely on non-portable tricks. Their priorities are also different from what you would generally see in production code, and they follow very different conventions. All-in-all it can be interesting to see how they work, but do not rely too much on this knowledge as learning material. There's no obvious way to tell between a smart implementation and a non-portable one.

Comment: Good points! Though I think if you're looking for a reason why your standard library types are reacting in an unexpected way. I'd think it's still a good idea to walk through those processes.