# Is omitting nested braces legal in initialization of `std::initializer_list` of aggregates?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, initializer-list

Consider following code:

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cinitializer_list%3E%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++int+x%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::initializer_list%3CA%3E%7B100%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g112,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang1300,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang1300,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+5/10%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct A
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::initializer_list<A>{100};
}
```

Clang accepts it. GCC and MSVC reject it, with errors like:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::initializer_list<A>::initializer_list(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

Which compiler is correct here?

I tried looking at [`[dcl.init.list]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#5) and [`[over.match.list]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list), but didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: I think technically GCC and MSVC are correct in this case, the second set of braces should be required.

Comment: Aren't you allowed to omit nested braces in brace init?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think that only applies to aggregates, and `std::initializer_list` does not need to be an aggregate.

Comment: @NathanOliver - But the underlying prvalue array it refers to *is* an aggregate.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - It's interesting to note the Clang also rejects the code if the `initializer_list` is in another context, such as a a function parameter https://godbolt.org/z/qWxTd37ET

Comment: _"Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list"_ seems to me the validity of the example is equivalent to `A a = 100;`, which is invalid.

Comment: _I tried looking at [dcl.init.list]/3.7_ Why (3.7) when `initializer_list` is handled in (3.6) + /5?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks, fixed.