# How come std::distance() doesn't work for rvalues?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
std::list <int> list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto first = list1.begin();

std::cout <<  std::distance(--first, ++first);
```

The output is 0. Strange enough, if we change `--first` to `first--`, the output becomes 5 (although here it should be 0, as it returns `first`). What am I missing?

Comment: Neither `--first` nor `++first` is an rvalue. `first++` and `first--` return rvalues though

Comment: 1. Both `--first` and `first--` applied to `list1.begin()` is undefined behaviour. 2. The evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified.

Comment: Can't you just replace everything with `std::cout <<  2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which the arguments in a function call are evaluated is unspecified.

`--first` may execute first or `++first` may execute first. If the former is the case, the decrement has undefined behavior, because decrementing a `.begin()` iterator is not allowed. Since one of the allowed execution orders has undefined behavior, your whole program has undefined behavior.

Using `first--` instead doesn't change anything about this.

Comment: Ok, my bad, but `distance(first, ++++first)` also outputs 0, where you would assuem it outputs 1

Comment: @Suspicious_1 My old comment repeated since I deleted it wrongly: In `distance(first, ++++first)` if the left-hand argument evaluates first, because `std::distance` takes the iterators by-value, the result will be `2`. If the right-hand argument evaluates first the result will be `0`. So both `0` and `2` are possible outputs since C++17.

Comment: @Suspicious_1 However, before C++17 the argument evaluations were allowed to interleave, so then it could have been possible to generate `1` as well, if the left-hand side is evaluated in-between the two increment operator calls. Whether this is still possible or not since C++17 seems to have some disagreement, although it seems to me that it shouldn't, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013035/function-argument-evaluation-and-side-effects).

Answer (score 1):

Neither `--first` nor `++first` is an rvalue. They are lvalues.

You are also not allowed to decrement the iterator returned by `begin()`.

To get the distance between two rvalues, you could use `std::prev` and `std::next`:

```cpp
auto second = std::next(list1.begin()); // to make std::prev(second) ok

std::cout <<  std::distance(std::prev(second), std::next(second));
```