# Undefined behaviour rules for i = ++i and the like

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have been brushing up on my undefined behaviour rules, and read the following:

[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/258418)
[Why is f(i = -1, i = -1) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21670459/258418)
[Why is `x-- > 0` not undefined behaviour, while `x = x--` is?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4924376/258418)

And
[In C++11, does `i += ++i + 1` exhibit undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24194076/258418)

And ended up with three questions:

1. Do the undefined behaviour rules for terms of the form `i=i++` apply to non integral types? (The expression should translate to `i.operator(i.operator++(i))`, and since each function call is a sequence point it should be well defined, if I understand the standard correctly)
2. Why is `f(i=-1, i=-1)` undefined behaviour in combination with "The result of the assignment operation is the value stored in the left operand after the assignment has taken place; the result is an lvalue" (ref)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/4190054/258418]? (I understand that the value of i is undefined afterwards, but the functioncall should be evaluated as `f(-1, -1)` if I understand the standard correctly.
3. Which types of expressions became safe with c++11/14/1z, only preincrement/predecrement in simple assignment (no `op=`)?

Comment: What do you mean by "became safe" in #3?

Comment: @Quentin: I do not insist on writing these montrosities, I will propably never go near them (I might have written something like `i=(++i)*x` instead of `i=(i+1)*x` once, but to avoid this I need a) awareness, b) be sure that the former is dangerous ( I agree that most examples are ugly/constructed).

Comment: @interjay: sorry i skipped the part mentioning the new c++ standard(s) (as far as I am aware there were changes with c++11)

Comment: @ted Don't worry, your question is a good one (I upvoted), I was just joking about the length of the running gag that sequence-point-triggered behaviour is becoming, even though no one would ever benefit from actually *using* such constructions :)

Comment: Why would `f(i=-1,i=-1)` leave `i` with an undefined value? If you were assigning to different numbers, it would make sense, but since you're assigning -1 twice, shouldn't `i` end up as -1?

Comment: @celticminstrel: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21671069/258418. While unlikely o be implemented this way it would be standard conformant to my understanding.

Comment: @ted #1 and #2 have already answers in the links you gived (not a direct answer for #1, but you can deduce it yourself)

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: For #2, I don;t see the answer that considers the bit of the standard cited. As for #1, you see my attempt in the question, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @ted #2 the undefined behavior is due to the two assignments not to the call arguments

Comment: For #2 I think it's critical to understand that undefined behaviour is more than a undefined value. I'd see it as a property of the whole programm, it might (in theory) do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about `f (i = -1, i = -1)`. Assume that you have two pointers `int* p` and `int* q`, and you call

```
f (*p = 1, *q = 2)
```

This is undefined behaviour if p == q. If you don't want it to be undefined behaviour, how would you define the behaviour in the case p == q? (Because if you don't like that it's undefined, you have to define it in some way). Further, would you accept a definition of the behaviour that means 99.999% of code might run a bit slower, to save some plainly idiotic code?

Then comes the case

```
f (*p = -1, *q = -1)
```

So the same value is assigned. If you want this to be defined behaviour, but not assigning different values, how on earth to you suggest putting that into a sensible rule?

Comment: I am not saying that it makes sense and we have the `restrict` keyword for the speed reason. (Where we actually pass the pointers into the function). I was more thinking that since `=` returns the value of the assignment, the function should be called with the correct arguments. I am still with you, as far as the definition of `p` and `q` for the next statement goes.

Comment: @ted What do you mean ? do you want the function to be called without making the assignments ?